# Nuxt-Bridge: [bridge] Bridge must be enabled by using defineNuxtConfig to wrap your Nuxt configuration

Tags: nuxt.js, nuxt-bridge

I'm currently trying to update from nuxt 2 to nuxt-bridge following this guide: https://v3.nuxtjs.org/bridge/overview

When running `nuxi dev` I receive this error message:

```
 FATAL  [bridge] Bridge must be enabled by using defineNuxtConfig to wrap your Nuxt configuration.         

  at setup (/XXX/node_modules/@nuxt/bridge/dist/chunks/module.mjs:1307:13)
  at ModuleContainer.normalizedModule (/XXX/node_modules/@nuxt/kit/dist/index.mjs:582:29)


 ERROR  Cannot start nuxt:  [bridge] Bridge must be enabled by using defineNuxtConfig to wrap your Nuxt configuration
.

  at setup (/XXX/node_modules/@nuxt/bridge/dist/chunks/module.mjs:1307:13)
  at ModuleContainer.normalizedModule (/XXX/node_modules/@nuxt/kit/dist/index.mjs:582:29)
```

However, as I consequently followed the migration guide, my `nuxt.config.ts` starts like this:

```
import { defineNuxtConfig } from '@nuxt/bridge'

export default defineNuxtConfig({
...
```

So, I consider that done. Not sure, what the error is trying to tell me. Any suggestions?

Sample repo: https://github.com/some-user123/nuxt-bridge

Comment: Tried that one? https://v3.nuxtjs.org/bridge/overview#ensure-everything-goes-well With `bridge: true` of course.

Comment: `yarn build` returns the same error, `bridge: true` is not allowed in typescript (`...not assignable to type 'false | Partial<BridgeConfig> | undefined'.`)
If I rename to `nuxt.config.js` and use `bridge: true`, same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bug (https://github.com/nuxt/bridge/issues/411), as a workaround `bridge: {}` can be used.